# preprocessing of LaTeX document before compiling in LyX

Tags: lyx

I'd like to be able to have the following workflow for my LyX documents:

1. Create the test.lyx file containing my writing
2. Export this to LaTeX to obtain test.tex
3. Apply a little text manipulation script I wrote in, say, perl, sed -or any other easily accessible linux script language- to test.tex
4. Compile test.tex

Is it possible to automate this, so that when I click compile all of the above steps execute ?

Comment: Yes, you can either create your own LyX converter from LaTeX -> PDF that calls a simple script that does the manipulation and then just runs LaTeX. If you do that, you need to handle all the LaTeX commands (e.g. know how many times to call `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, etc. Another approach is to create a new format PDF_customized, then create a converter LaTeX -> LaTeX_customized and then LaTeX_customized->PDF_customized. It will take some time for you to learn how to do this, but all of the information is in Help > Customization.

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks, this is great help. Would it be possible to expand  one approach slightly in form of an answer (assuming my script flle is called "manip") ? Am I right that the second approach is the faster one ?

Comment: sorry I am currently spending most of my free time to help with the LyX 2.2.0 release (which will be out soon). Hopefully someone else can provide a full answer. I hope my comment at least points you in the right direction for developing the solution yourself. The information you'll learn by doing it yourself about LyX converters and file formats will be very helpful to understanding LyX. It would be a good investment of time.